# Is is possible to remove a everyplay instance when poping out the GLKviewController ffrom UINavigationcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, opengl-es-2.0, everyplay

I want to use everyplay to record video from a GLKViewController. Well I have no such problem in recording but my app crashes during repeated navigation. What I am doing is, I load a view controller on which there is a view (GLKView) of GLKViewController added as subview for which Everyplay is setup to record. When I pop out the view controller in use and try to load the same view controller again, content on the GLKView becomes black and crashes my app.

The error given after crash is:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVAssetWriterInput initWithMediaType:outputSettings:sourceFormatHint:] AVVideoSettings dictionary must specify a positive width'

So I guess I need to remove the EveryPlay or EveryPlayCapture instance so that I can create it again?

Is is possible to remove them? or is there any other method by which I can solve this problem?

Comment: Please paste a code you are using

Comment: I think I kind of solved it. I am using Sparrow Framework's SPViewController which is a subclass of GLKViewController. I retained the SPViewController's instance and reuse it when needed but I havn't checked if this method has any memory implications or not.

Comment: Okey - I have ready integration with Sparrow older version if you need I can share - because they are not supporting it too well - especially rotations. But on Sparrow 2.0 I guess it's easier.

Comment: I have integrated Everyplay with sparrow 2.0 so I won't be needing it to integrate with Sparrow 1.0. I followed the clue from EveryplayGLKit example available in github and various hit and trials. Also I am using Everyplay version 1.5 because v1.6 has issue regarding AVFoundation where AVAudioPlayer delegates are not called.

Comment: The delegate methods are now called in the v1.6.3 version of Everyplay. You may also set your capturer nil to release it incase you deallocate your OpenGL view during your app lifetime.